# Linking/unlinking jquery object to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery flowplayer tools plugin http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip.html

1)I want a tooltip to be created when user clicks on an element.

2)When the user clicks on another element, the old tooltip must be unlinked(deleted)

3)A new tooltip should be created(or old moved to) for the clicked element

4)So, there should <=1 tooltip on the page

Can you please help me?

Here's the code, it runs standalone

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
    <title>jQuery tooltip</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


/******* THIS FUNCTION IS JUST FOR TEST, REMOVE IT LATER *********/
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#_2").tooltip({ 
            effect: "slide", 
            tip: '.tooltip' ,
            position: 'bottom center'
        }); 

    });
/******* THIS FUNCTION IS JUST FOR TEST, REMOVE IT LATER *********/




/** The code below is not working as I expect, it doesn't MOVE tooltip **/

           var old_id;

    //first time - create tooltip
        function my_create(id){
            $("#"+id).tooltip({ 
                effect: "slide", 
                tip: '.tooltip', 
                position: 'bottom center'
            });     
        }

     //next times - move tooltip to other element
        function my_unlink(id){
            $("#"+id).unbind("mouseover"); 
            //todo
        }

        function my_link(id){
            //todo
        }


        //THE MAIN FUNCTION

        function do_tip(new_id){
            if(old_id){
                my_unlink(old_id);
                my_link(new_id);
                alert(new_id);
            }
            else
                my_create(new_id);

            old_id=new_id;
         //new_id.focus();
     } 

    </script> 

  <style>
    .tooltip {
      display: none;
      background:transparent url(http://flowplayer.org/tools/img/tooltip/black_arrow_bottom.png);
      font-size:14px;
      height:70px;
      width:160px;
      padding:25px;
      color:#fff;   
    }
    h1 {
      width: 400px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 onclick="do_tip(this.id)" id="_1">John</h1>
    <h1 onclick="do_tip(this.id)" id="_2">Mary</h1>
    <h1 onclick="do_tip(this.id)" id="_3">Dan</h1>
    <h1 onclick="do_tip(this.id)" id="_4">Paul</h1>
    <h1 onclick="do_tip(this.id)" id="_5">Kim</h1>

    <div class="tooltip">There should be only one tooltip on a page!</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Does the call to tooltip() return anything? Is there an object representing the tooptip that might have a remove or delete method?

Comment: 1)call to tooltip() returns the jquery object and it can also return library-specific API. 2)No, there is no delete() destructor in the library =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery tools tooltip supports defining which events trigger the tooltip.

You do not need to handle the click event by yourself.

Edit: Updated the script. Click on the link to move the tooltip to the second element always.

Here is the [script](http://jsbin.com/ubuqa/9/)

```
var tt = $("h1").tooltip({
  events:{def:'click, click'},
  effect: "slide",
  tip: '.tooltip' ,
  position: "bottom center",
  api: true,
  delay: 30000
});

$("#ht").click(function() {
  tt.hide();
  $("#_2").tooltip().show();
});
```

The whole script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
<style>
    .tooltip {
      display: none;
      background:transparent url(http://flowplayer.org/tools/img/tooltip/black_arrow_bottom.png);
      font-size:14px;
      height:70px;
      width:160px;
      padding:25px;
      color:#fff;   
    }
    h1 {
      width: 400px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: yellow;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

 </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="_1">John</h1>
    <h1 id="_2">Mary</h1>
    <h1 id="_3">Dan</h1>
    <h1 id="_4">Paul</h1>
    <h1 id="_5">Kim</h1>

    <a id="ht" href="javascript:void()">Click here</a>
    <div class="tooltip">There should be only one tooltip on a page!</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>

var tt = $("h1").tooltip({
  events:{def:'click, click'},
  effect: "toggle",
  tip: '.tooltip' ,
  position: "bottom center",
  api: true,
  delay: 30000
});

$("#ht").click(function() {
  tt.hide();
  setTimeout(function(){$("#_2").tooltip().show();}, 500);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, working!
In your exaple - is it possible to remove a click event and instead trigger the tooltip prorammaticaly for specific id like this: function hover_tooltip(id){ /*todo*/}
//PS: There must me <=1 tooltip on the page

Comment: Do you want an element with specific id to show the tooltip when hovered on or trigger it upon some other condition programatically?

When will the hover_tooltip(id) be called?

Comment: I mean hovering on some program action. For example these tooltips can work great in form validation.

Comment: I need a to call a function hover_tooltip(id) to create a tooltip an an element and delete old tooltip

Answer (score 1):

The FlowPlayer Tooltip has an API that is returned on EVERY call to `tooltip`.

You can then call `hide` on the API object.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
    var old_id, API;

//first time - create tooltip
    function my_create(id){
        API = $("#"+id).tooltip({ 
            effect: "slide", 
            tip: '.tooltip', 
            position: 'bottom center'
        });     
    }

 //next times - move tooltip to other element
    function my_unlink(id){
        API.unbind("mouseover"); 
        //todo
    }

    function my_link(id){
        my_create( id );
    }


    //THE MAIN FUNCTION

    function do_tip(new_id){
        if(old_id){
            my_unlink(old_id);
            my_link(new_id);
            alert(new_id);
        }
        else
            my_create(new_id);

        old_id=new_id;
     //new_id.focus();
 }
```

Comment: OOps! Try clicking John, Mary and John again

Answer (score 1):

How about this alternative solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
    <title>jQuery tooltip</title>
    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h1").tooltip({ 
            effect: "slide", 
            tip: '.tooltip' ,
            position: 'bottom center',
            onBeforeShow: function(event){
                //don't show tooltip if trigger (h1 object) does not have specified class
                if(!this.getTrigger().hasClass("hasToolTip")) 
                    return false;                       
            }
        }); 

        $("h1").click(function() {
            $("h1").removeClass("hasToolTip");
            $(this).addClass("hasToolTip");
        }); 
    });

    </script> 

  <style>
    .tooltip {
      display: none;
      background:transparent url(http://flowplayer.org/tools/img/tooltip/black_arrow_bottom.png);
      font-size:14px;
      height:70px;
      width:160px;
      padding:25px;
      color:#fff;   
    }
    h1 {
      width: 400px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="_1">John</h1>
    <h1 id="_2">Mary</h1>
    <h1 id="_3">Dan</h1>
    <h1 id="_4">Paul</h1>
    <h1 id="_5">Kim</h1>

    <div class="tooltip">There should be only one tooltip on a page!</div>

</body></html>
```