# How to destroy the imageflow jquery plugin instance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, imageflow

has anyone worked with imageflow jquery plugin? Do you know how to destroy an instance? When I remove with jquery the structure that this plugin creates, the events of the plugin continue to be triggered. Any idea or tip how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I guess this is a general question; how to destroy an object that was created and assigned several events?

Comment: Ever considered  as well voting? Look, you've got one upvote ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply unbinding the events associated with the object:

```
theObject.unbind()
```

Also, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124327/linking-unlinking-jquery-object-to-an-element) - it looks similar, and may help